# Django. How to connect drop-down list (from html) and forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-widget

A have a field in model (name model is Users_data):

```
bir_date = models.DateField(verbose_name="")
```

And form which represents model:

```
class Form_registration (ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Users_data
```

in html:

```
<form name="registration" method="post" action="save_data_user/">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form_registration.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="SignUp">
</form>
```

View which saves form:

```
def saves_data_user_on_registration (request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    form_user_data = Form_registration(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form_user_data.is_valid():
        print form_user_data.errors
        form_user_data.save()
        return render_to_response('see_you_later.html', c,           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        print form_user_data.errors
        return render_to_response('error.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I can save simple data in form.

But I need save a data in drop-down list from html in field from my model Users_data.

```
<select name="DateOfBirth_Month">
<option>Month</option>
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
...



 <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
 <option value="-1" selected>Day</option>
 <option value="1">01</option>
 <option value="2">02</option>
 ...

<select name="DateOfBirth_Year">
<option>Year</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
...
```

And I don't understand how I can to connect drop-down list with my form or model.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) and set it for the `DateField` using [`widgets` on the `Meta` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).

A good example of the particular widget that splits year, month and day into separate dropdowns can be found in Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget.format_output), see `DateSelectorWidget`:

```
class Form_registration (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users_data
        widgets = {'bir_date': widgets.DateSelectorWidget()}
```

This code assumes you've created a `widgets.py` module with `DateSelectorWidget` class inside.

Another good widget for the task is [`django.forms.extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget):

> Wrapper around three Select widgets: one each for month, day, and
>   year.

Also see:

- [Django SelectDateWidget to show month and year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733098/django-selectdatewidget-to-show-month-and-year-only)
- [django-datetime-widget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-datetime-widget)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I have a error: Cannot find reference 'DateSelectorWidget' in widgets.py

Comment: Although I'm import widgets - from django.forms import widgets

Comment: @user3636189 if you wanna go with the first option, having `DateSelectorWidget` custom widget, you should create it in `widgets.py` file and then import it. But, I would start with trying out `django.forms.extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use a choices attribute for your `DateField` in the model.

Here is how to do it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/